# How to fix blank user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I've created a userControl that is filled with buttons, labels, text boxes, etc.  When I add it to my FormMain, what appears just a 150x150 grey square instead of what my userControl should look like.  I've other userControls in this project, and they function just fine. No code currently provided because, based on my other userControls, this should be happening with winforms - with both UC's, I am simply dragging and dropping from the toolbox.

Image of what happens when I add one of the "other" userControls:

[image: Image of what happens when I add one of the "other" userControls]

Image of what happens when I add the desired userControl:

[image: Image of what happens when I add the desired userControl]

Image of what my userControl actually looks like:

[image: Image of what my userControl actually looks like]

In the form main designer, they're added to the tab here...

```
this.tabPageTelescope.Controls.Add(this.userControlTelescope21);
this.tabPageTelescope.Controls.Add(this.userControlTelescope1);
```

Later on, they appear again here.

```
// userControlTelescope1
// 
this.userControlTelescope1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(113, 55);
this.userControlTelescope1.Name = "userControlTelescope1";
this.userControlTelescope1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
this.userControlTelescope1.TabIndex = 0;
// 
// userControlTelescope21
// 
this.userControlTelescope21.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(236, 13);
this.userControlTelescope21.Name = "userControlTelescope21";
this.userControlTelescope21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(752, 587);
this.userControlTelescope21.TabIndex = 1;
```

Both userControlTelescope21 is the one that is appearing as expected, userControl1 is the one that is being problematic.  They have identical properties, aside from the TabIndex.  Might be worth noting that the size for userControlTelescope1 is not (150,150) - that's what it's adding it as though.

Comment: You need to provide something more. Either code or screen shots (or even better, both). Without that, it seems unlikely, that anyone will be able to assist you.

Comment: Noceo is right. We can only guess. It could be an issue with the size of the UserControl.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help.  I should have thought to add screenshots in the beginning.  They've been added.  @Noceo, the userControl that is not displaying properly is actually a smaller size than the one that is.

Comment: Do you have another control, like a blank panel, inside the TabPage?  userControlTelescope1 looks like the right size based on the image, but the location doesn't match the code.  Location (8, 35) should be much closer to the left edge.

Comment: @LarsTech I do not.  The TabPage is/was empty until I added userControlTelescope1, and userControlTelescope21.  I checked then, but just checked again to be sure.  The code and the images were not taken at the same time, hence the wrong placement.  That was silly of me.  Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: The size of userControlTelescope is (694,620).  Regardless of how I size it, it's being added as a (150,150) square.  It might also be worth mentioning that the square is transparent.

Comment: `square is transparent` Did you make it transparent?  Or are you saying it looks transparent?  Change the BackColor to something else in the UserControl and see if it isn't "transparent" anymore.  Any chance the controls on the UserControl are all visible = false?

Comment: @LarsTech I did not make it transparent. The Backcolor on my UC is "control".  The size of my UC is (694, 624).  Once I add my UC to the FormMain, however, the BackColor of the added one is Transparent, and the size changes is (150,15).  The properties of my "nonworking" UC (aside from size and tabIndex) are the same as the "working" UC.  When I add my "nonworking" UC to the FormMain, it's properties change and it's nothing like it was prior to being added.  The other UC's do not have this problem.

Comment: Just to rule out anything obvious what happens if you do this in a completely new project without any other parent controls interfering?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of without code is making sure your controls are members of the tab pane and not the underlying form. Look at the properties panel for them or the code for the form designer.

Comment: Hi, Will.  I've just added some code.  It's my understanding that they're being added to the tab pane via the first bit of code.  I could be missing something, though, as I am new to C#.  The properties, aside from TabIndex, are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this same problem.  After an afternoon of pulling out (what's left of) my hair, I came to the awful realization that I had done something silly:

***Somehow, somewhere along the line, the call to InitializeComponent() in the constructor got deleted.***

On account of that, the control is painted as an empty void both in design and when the app is running.

Comment: don't get why this was downvoated - this is the main key for the answer...look why initializeComponent won't be called.